# Linear Search Problem

Tags: c#, algorithm, linear-search

My program has no compile errors but the output is incorrect. Example input:

size of array: 5
input numbers: 5 4 3 2 1
//sorted: 1 2 3 4 5
search: 1
output: number 1 found at index 4

the output should be number 1 found at index 0 since the numbers were sorted already. How will I change it to this.

```
    int[] nums = new int[100];
    int SizeNum;
    bool isNum = false;

    private void ExeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, loc, key;
        Boolean found = false;
        string SizeString = SizeTextBox.Text;
        isNum = Int32.TryParse(SizeString, out SizeNum);
        string[] numsInString = EntNum.Text.Split(' ');   //split values in textbox
        for (int j = 0; j < numsInString.Length; j++)
        {
            nums[j] = int.Parse(numsInString[j]);
        }
        if (SizeNum == numsInString.Length)
        {
            Array.Sort(numsInString);
            key = int.Parse(SearchTextBox.Text);
            ResultText.AppendText("Sorted: ");
            for (i = 0; i < SizeNum; i++)
                ResultText.AppendText(" " + numsInString[i]);
                 ResultText.AppendText("\n\n");
            {
                for (loc = 0; loc < SizeNum; loc++)
                {
                    if (nums[loc] == key)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (found == true)
                    ResultText.AppendText("Number " + key + " Found At Index [" + loc + "]\n\n");
                else
                    ResultText.AppendText("Number " + key + " Not Found!\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like anything but linear search.

Comment: Your program clearly *does* have an error, as it doesn't do what you want it to...

Comment: It looks a lot like lineair search. The last part that is. The Sort() isn't necessary though, and it is wrong if you want the position in the input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting `numsInString` but then searching `nums`. `nums` is being populated *before* the search, so you're seeing the results of searching the unsorted numbers.

Once you've parsed `numsInStrings` into `nums`, you should be working with the latter array only. Make sure that's the one you're sorting and searching through.

In other words, once you replace the current sort call with

```
Array.Sort(nums);
```

your code will be fine.

**Updated**:

You actually need another fix. Right now, you're initializing `nums` to be an array of size 100. By default, each element will be 0. So even though you put numbers in the first five elements, when you sort the array, you end up with 95 0's, followed by 1 2 3 4 5.

You should delay initializing `nums` until you've seen how big `numsInString` is:

```
string[] numsInString = EntNum.Text.Split(' ');   //split values in textbox
nums = new int[numsInString.Length];

for (int j = 0; j < numsInString.Length; j++)
{
    nums[j] = int.Parse(numsInString[j]);
}
```

Now when you sort `nums`, you'll see only the numbers you entered.

Comment: That and you're sorting the string array instead of the int array, which I don't think is what you intended to do.

Comment: @crlanglous Right; changing the sort to the `nums` array solves both problems.

Comment: That was my first option. Array.Sort(nums);. But it displays zeros. Then I change it to NumInstring.

Comment: It displays correctly now. That's why I'm seeing a lot of zeros. I missed something on my codes. Thanks dlev.

Answer (score 1):

you are sorting the `numsInString` array, but still searching into the `nums` array.

```
for (loc = 0; loc < SizeNum; loc++)
{
    if (numsInString[loc] == key)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing `numsInString` *then* you're sorting it. (I suspect the sort won't do what you want, either.)

I think you really want to be sorting `nums` instead:

```
Array.Sort(nums);
```

Having said that, there are simpler ways of achieving the end result - such as using `IndexOf` to find the index of a value in an array.

It's also rather unclear why you've got braces here:

```
for (i = 0; i < SizeNum; i++)
    ResultText.AppendText(" " + numsInString[i]);
    ResultText.AppendText("\n\n");
{
    ...
}
```

That makes it *look* like you've got a loop with a body, but it's actually equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < SizeNum; i++)
{
    ResultText.AppendText(" " + numsInString[i]);
}
ResultText.AppendText("\n\n");
{
    ...
}
```

... the braces serve no purpose here, and merely harm readability.